# Using setState in .forEach loop will only run callback function with most recent state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a tempAddList that will contain a list of id's that I will set the state into the relInfo table and callback the addRelation function to submit the data. But when I run onAddClick for example if the tempAddList = [2,3,4]
it would run addRelation 3 times with the latest setState id 4 but not 2 and 3. How would I get it to run for each individual id.

```
 onAddClick = () => {
    this.state.tempAddList.forEach((id) => {
        this.setState({
            relInfo: {
                ...this.state.relInfo,
                modId: id
            }
        }, () => this.addRelation());
    });
};

addRelation = () => {
    EdmApi.insertModifier(this.state.relInfo)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: you are overriding `relInfo` in each iteration.

Comment: why are you changing the state in every iteration of the loop?

Comment: I need to submit an object with other information to my insertModifier api call. All the information is the same I just need to submit it with a different modId

Comment: I just noticed I answered the very same question here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53857274/3731501 . Did it not work? There was no feedback.

Comment: sorry about that I get an infinite loop of addRelation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `this.state` together with `setState` is an antipattern. This may result in race conditions because state updates are asynchronous. This is use case for [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Several `setState` calls will result in batch update, with `addRelation` called with latest updated state.

A workaround is to not update in batch and wait for state update, e.g. [with `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53080853/3731501):

```
async onAddClick = () => {
    const setStateAsync = updater => new Promise(resolve => this.setState(updater, resolve));

    for (const id of this.state.tempAddList) {
        await setStateAsync(state => ({
            relInfo: {
                ...state.relInfo,
                modId: id
            }
        });
        this.addRelation();
    });
};
```

A preferable solution is to not rely on state updates in side effects (`addRelation`). The purpose of `state` is to be used in `render`. If state updates don't affect view (only the latest `modId` update will be shown), they aren't needed:

```
 onAddClick = () => {
    let { relInfo } = this.state;
    this.state.tempAddList.forEach((id) => {
        relInfo = { ...relInfo, modId: id };
        this.addRelation(relInfo);
    });

    this.setState({ relInfo });
};

addRelation = (relInfo) => {
    EdmApi.insertModifier(relInfo);
};
```

If `modId` isn't used in `render`, it could be excluded from the state. In this specific case the absence of updater function shouldn't be a problem because click handlers are triggered asynchronously, it's unlikely that they will cause race conditions by interfering with state updates.

Comment: I get an error stating index.js:2178 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: Given that `onAddClick` is really triggered on click as the name suggests, it shouldn't result in this error, so the error is irrelevant to the code you posted. There may be another problem in your code.

Comment: but it still only runs addRelation witht he latest Id

Comment: Btw, what's the purpose of having `modId` in state? Do you display it in `render`? The answer may depend on that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't display it on render but there is an object in my state that I manipulate based on given information by the user and I submit that object to add or delete information.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Hope this helped.